# Name for: thumbnail getting big and spreads text?

Tags: terminology, image, modal-windows, resizing

Is there a common name or plugin for the function when a thumbnail gets resized to a bigger image and spreads the surrounding text?

It is similar to a modal view, but imho more user friendly.

[Example](http://www.idowa.de/region/artikel/2014/06/30/schneller-als-der-wind-ein-tag-mit-einem-luftbeobachter.html) (click the image showing the cockpit view)

Example before clicking:
[image]

Example after clicking:
[image]

Comment: I'd say this is sort of like a non-conventional Accordion? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: @BenBrocka not really. Technically the image gets replaces (and zoomed). Accordion shows content below the heading (or in my case the thumbnail)

Comment: Ohhh you mean the big image not the little ones. Huh. Not really sure there's a word for it other than zooming

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a compact name for the interaction. You see this very often on design portfolios.

Here's two plugins

Thumbnail grid with Expanding preview: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

Portfolio content expander: http://codecanyon.net/item/colio-jquery-portfolio-content-expander-plugin/6507310

Answer (score 0):

In typography, big starting letters dropping over a few lines are called "**drop caps**" (see http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/drop_cap).

[image]

The idea is similar with small pictures featured at the beginning of an article.

Since yours are zoomable, they could be called "**zoomable drop pics**".

Comment: Great idea. If I will create a framework, I will name it so;) But atm I search for some exiting framework or common naming.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. My own inital functional approach: [imgspread](https://github.com/klml/imgspread) ([demo](http://klml.github.io/imgspread/))